# UISwipeActionsConfiguration with NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate updates

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableViewDataSource that's also a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

On the table's delegate I implement: (completionHandler omitted on purpose here)

```
func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in

      let object = self.object(at: indexPath)

      do {
        try ObjectManager.delete(object)
      } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
      }
    }

    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true
    return config
  }
```

On the data source I conform the fetched results controller delegate like this:

```
extension UserPrescriptionsTableViewDataSource: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

  // MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

  func controllerWillChangeContent(
    _ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView?.beginUpdates()
  }

  func controller(
    _ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>,
    didChange anObject: Any,
    at indexPath: IndexPath?,
    for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
    newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch type {

    case .delete:
      guard let path = indexPath else { return }
      tableView?.deleteRows(at: [path], with: .automatic)
    case .insert:
      guard let newPath = newIndexPath else { return }
      tableView?.insertRows(at: [newPath], with: .automatic)
    case .move:
      guard let path = indexPath, let newPath = newIndexPath else { return }
      tableView?.deleteRows(at: [path], with: .automatic)
      tableView?.insertRows(at: [newPath], with: .automatic)
    case .update:
      guard let path = indexPath else { return }
      tableView?.reloadRows(at: [path], with: .automatic)
    }
  }

  func controllerDidChangeContent(
    _ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView?.endUpdates()
  }
}
```

The swipe action updates does or does not update the UI via the completionHandler that's invoked in the action's own block here:

```
completionHandler(true) // animates row removal
completionHandler(false) // does not remove the row
```

My issues is that the swipe animation *feels right* in use, when I return false in the action's completion the delegate does remove the row but it doesn't match the user's actions as nicely. In trial I avoid duplicate calls by:

I've tried:

- I asked the data source to ask the table's delegate if it should process calls from the fetched results controller delegate - this worked out ok but I'd get inconsistency exceptions around some edge cases (I want to continue down this path but wanted to ask a question first in case I was turning a molehill into a mountain :)).
- Ignoring the problem but it won't go away

Comment: What you mean by user actions nicely?

Comment: The actual swipe itself, when provided true in the handler feels like the row's removal matches nicely with the user's swipe.

Comment: Then why do you want to send false?

Comment: So that the fetched results controller delegate can handle the removal of the row.

Comment: @FredFaust I understand what you are saying - what conclusion did you come to in this matter?